# Преобразовать Json в html

Tags: php, json

Всем привет!
Есть сайт, у которого товары в категориях выводятся в JSON, какие есть способы, **желательно несколько** (на лету), которые могли бы преобразовать json в html.

Comment: сначала преобразуете json в массив или объект, потом используете или шаблонизатор или делаете html строку

Comment: Можно более детально? То есть сейчас CMS выводит товары в JSON, нам нужно этот код JSON на лету преобразовать в массив  и после использовать шаблонизатор? Что за шаблонизатор?

Comment: я не представляю что у вас за cms, как строятся страницы и тд, поэтому больше сказать не могу

Comment: К сожалению нужно больше вариантов, чтобы понять какие способы можно реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать javascript, можно в тег pre обернуть

Comment: Ахааа, неее такой вариант не подойдет.