# Как вывести информацию json импортированную через JS, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было преобразовать в текст на html странице?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, веб-программирование, mongodb

Нет, это не [дубликат данного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005522/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%b2-html). У меня другая проблема.

Реализовал небольшое API для самообразования. После этого загружаю его себе на localhost:3000.

Затем я создаю в отдельной папке легендарное "трио" из html, css b js. Вот, собственно код импорта в JS.

```js
fetch("http:/localhost:3000")
  .then((result) => {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

И вот собственно вопрос: каким именно методом я могу оперировать полученный данные? Понимаю, вопрос наверняка глупый, однако хотелось бы получить либо ответ, либо ссылку на ресурс с описанием решения. Заранее огромное вам спасибо!

P.S. API представляет у меня из себя просто возможность подавать запрос в базу данных MongoDB и записывать/изменять/удалять оттуда данные.

Вот пример моего лога консоли:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
date: "2020-07-10T13:31:34.504Z"
description: "That worked"
title: "The testing of the MongoDB"
__v: 0
_id: "5f086db67cfb94f8143fe642"
__proto__: Object
1:
date: "2020-07-10T14:07:22.108Z"
description: "That worked, but with using async now."
title: "The testing of the MongoDB"
__v: 0
_id: "5f08761a83c659f5e0423d78"
__proto__: Object
2:
date: "2020-07-10T14:13:28.756Z"
description: "That worked, but with using async now. And using the listing of all posts."
title: "The testing of the MongoDB"
__v: 0
_id: "5f087788b3fa81d9281f65ec"
__proto__: Object
3:
date: "2020-07-10T14:51:24.254Z"
description: "This will be updated"
title: "Updated"
__v: 0
_id: "5f08806cb6a83dff58968f0f"
__proto__: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту проблему не через `fetch`, а через `XMLHttpRequest`.

Вот, что получилось в конечном итоге, чисто для примера. Вытащил из json Имя и описание первого объекта.

```js
const requestURL = "http://localhost:3000";

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", requestURL);
request.responseType = "json";
request.send();

request.onload = function () {
  const jsonDB = request.response;
  makeTitles(jsonDB);
  makeDescriptions(jsonDB);
  console.log(request.response);
};

function makeTitles(jsonObj) {
  let title = document.createElement("h1");
  title.textContent = jsonObj[0]["title"];
  document.getElementById("header").appendChild(title);
}

function makeDescriptions(jsonObj) {
  let description = document.createElement("h2");
  description.textContent = jsonObj[0]["description"];
  document.getElementById("header").appendChild(description);
}
```